# var b :Int = _ is giving compile error

Tags: scala

When I run this code 
1) var b :Int = _ . Its running fine on terminal

But when I run in IDE, it gives compilation error.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: local variables must be initialized

Answer (score 4):

> Point to note: Default initialisation of variable works inside a class or object but, it does not work inside a function (local variable).

You are trying to use default value initialization inside a function

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def foo(a: Int): Int = {
var b: Int = _
a
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:12: error: local variables must be initialized
       var b: Int = _
           ^
```

Its Ok to use this inside a class or object

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Foo {
var i: Int = _
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Foo
```

With object

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Bar {
var i: Int = _
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object Bar
```

Why it works on REPL?

```
scala> var i: Int = _
i: Int = 0
```

Everything written directly on REPL prompt will be wrapped by default by an object, that is why we do NOT get this error on REPL.

In order to prove this claim that by default what ever is written on REPL is wrapped by an object. lets write a small function to using `this` which refers to the current object in context.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def experiment(): Unit = println(s"${this.getClass}")
experiment()

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

class $line13.$read$$iw$$iw$
experiment: ()Unit
```

Cool! It works. Our code is wrapped around by this container `$line13.$read$$iw$$iw$`